# Conditional binding from view model to view in WPF using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I am developing a WPF application using MVVM pattern. I have a combo in the view and two lists in the viewmodel (projects and organizations). Depending on the organizations list items I have to bind the the name of the organization or not. 
For example if the Count property of the organizations list is 1 the combobox item have to be **"ProjectName"**, and if the Count property of the organizations list is greater than 1 the combobox item should look like **"ProjectName - OrganizationName"**.
This is the XAML code I have:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="textBox3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Projects}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedProject}">
        </ComboBox>
```

How should I achieve this purpose. I hope for a little help. Cheers.

I added the property projectFullName in the viewmodel but I got an empty combobox:

```
 public string ProjectFullName
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.organizations.ToList().Count > 1)
            {
                this.projectFullName = string.Format("{}{0} - {1}", this.selectedProject.Name, this.organizations.First(org => org.Id == this.selectedProject.OrganizationId).Name);
            }
            else if (this.organizations.ToList().Count == 1)
            {
                this.projectFullName = this.selectedProject.Name;
            }
            return this.projectFullName;
        }
    }
```

XAML code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="textBox3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Projects}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=ProjectFullName}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedProject}">

        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: You need to use datatemplate and datatriggers

Comment: but how can I use it, would you give me an example

Comment: google is your friend, there are plenty of examples out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have several options to implement this, but in my opinion the best is:

Add a property to your Data Context, the will be called "FullName" or something.
That will return: (Pseudo)
if Projects count > 0 then 
    return Name + '-' + ProjectName
else return Name

then bind DisplayMemberPath to FullName.

Comment: how can i bind to displaymemebrPath, because now the combobox items are not shown after I bind the property I created in the viewmodel.

Comment: The "FullName" property is not created in viewmodel.
the ItemsSource DataContext is set to the model list, so the DataContext is the model, therefore you need to create FullName in the model, and then bind DisplayMemberPath to it.

Answer (score 0):

Datatrigger is indeed your friend. Make sure the ComboBox does not set the DisplayMemberPath, because that will override the style setters.

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle"  TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="DefaultName"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="OtherName"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```